# How to use defined in class file with namespace

Tags: constants, namespace

Here is my code.

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

namespace JSR;

class myClass{
...
}
```

This is giving below error

```
Global code should be enclosed in global namespace declaration
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the PHP manual on [defining namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php):

> Namespaces are declared using the namespace keyword. **A file containing
>   a namespace must declare the namespace at the top of the file before
>   any other code - with one exception: the *declare* keyword.**

To fix the issue, simply make sure that your namespace declaration comes before the other code:

```
namespace JSR;

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

class myClass{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Use" keyword, to access your class of that namespace.